# Unable to convert numeric percentage to string

Tags: excel, vba, format

I am trying to run a "select case" where if the value in question belongs to the designated ranges, it converts the value to a string:

EX: `if pr = 70% in cell`, it will be converted to a string as "70%", not as 0.7

I've noticed when just using a place holder variable it converts the string (i.e. "`p= = CStr(pr * 100 & "%")`" vs "`pr = CStr(pr * 100 & "%")`"

```
Private RCN_pars, pr As Range  'databody range of parameters 

Select Case pr.Column
            Case Range("RCNS_U[Enhanced Contrast]").Column, 
     Range("RCNS_U[Recon Mode]").Column, _
            Range("RCNS_U[IQ Enhance]").Column, 
     Range("RCNS_U[Interval]").Column, Range("RCNS_U[Flip/Rotate]").Column
                GoTo NextCell
            Case Range("RCNS_U[ASiR-V]").Column, Range("RCNS_U[Phase]").Column  'convert percentages
                pr = CStr(pr * 100) & "%"
        End Select
```

pr gets defined as numeric value 70, not "70%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `.NumberFormat` property of a `Range`, like this:

```
pr.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
```

In your code it would be like this:

```
Private RCN_pars, pr As Range  'databody range of parameters 

Select Case pr.Column
    Case Range("RCNS_U[Enhanced Contrast]").Column, _ 
        Range("RCNS_U[Recon Mode]").Column, _
        Range("RCNS_U[IQ Enhance]").Column, _
        Range("RCNS_U[Interval]").Column, Range("RCNS_U[Flip/Rotate]").Column
        GoTo NextCell
    Case Range("RCNS_U[ASiR-V]").Column, Range("RCNS_U[Phase]").Column  'convert percentages
        pr.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
End Select
```

Comment: Nice. I had never heard of that method before.